# PySimpleGUI - Multiline resize window when I'm updating text font size

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pysimplegui

I'm using "sg.Multiline" to display some text.
I want to change to bigger text font on the fly by updating the text font like this :
window['result'].update("some text", text_color='red',font=(10,10))

As a result of this method the window itself and the "Multiline" element change size as well to be very unreasonably big...
I want to maintain the original size of the window and the Multiline element and just display bigger text font.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The size of Multiline element is decided by the font size, so it will changed if you update the font size.

> The default font for text inserted into the widget. Note that you can have
> multiple fonts in the widgets by using tags to change the properties of some
> text.

Using tag configuration to change the attributes of some text with tag.
tkinter code required here.

```py
from random import randint
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def random_color():
    return '#%02X%02X%02X' % (randint(0,255), randint(0,255), randint(0,255))

def random_size():
    return randint(8, 16)

font = ('Courier New', 12)

layout = [
    [sg.Multiline('', size=(40, 10), font=font, key='-ML-')],
    [sg.Push(), sg.Button('Hello World'), sg.Push()]
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)
# Get tkinter widget after window finalized
multiline = window['-ML-'].widget
count = 0

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Hello World':
        tag_name = f'Tag {count}'
        # Insert text to end of the multiline with tag name
        multiline.insert(sg.tk.END, 'Hello World ', (tag_name,))
        color, size = random_color(), random_size()
        # Configure the attributes for the text with this tag_name
        multiline.tag_configure(tag_name, foreground=color, font=('Arial', size))
        # Autoscroll to the end of multiline when necessary
        multiline.see(sg.tk.END)
        count += 1

window.close()
```

[image]